# Swift Selector is never called for NSTimer

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have the following instance method in my Swift class `Sentence` which makes a call to a `NSTimer` which calls the class instance method as its Selector. When I run the program without breakpoints, it gets to the first `NSTimer` successfully but then stalls at `NSTimer`. When I add a breakpoint to see if `sentenceDidFinish` is ever called, I see that it never is, proving it stops at the first `NSTimer`.

```
class Sentence : NSObject {
   //init() etc.

   func playEvent(eventIndex : Int){
       if (eventIndex < 2){
           let currEvent = self.eventArray[eventIndex]
           currEvent.startEvent()
           let nextIndex = eventIndex + 1
           print("Play Event event id is ", eventIndex)
           NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(currEvent.duration, target: self, selector: Selector("playEvent:"), userInfo: NSNumber(integer: nextIndex), repeats: false)
       }
       else if (eventIndex==2){
         self.eventArray[eventIndex].startEvent()
         print("Play Event event id is ", eventIndex)
         NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("sentenceDidFinish"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
      }
      else{
        //DO Nothing
      }
  }

  func sentenceDidFinish(){
    //foo
    //bar
  }

}
```

Here is the full .swift file:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0839eae1d77e1e4b671

Comment: Are you calling this on a thread that has a runloop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `playEvent:` with the timer, the argument passed will be the timer itself, not the integer. But in the declaration for `eventIndex` you are acting as if it will be the integer.

Try adding a method like this:

```
func handleTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
    playEvent(timer.userInfo as! Int)
}
```

Then call the first timer like this:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "handleTimer:", userInfo: NSNumber(integer: nextIndex), repeats: false)
```

---

The forced casting (`as!`) will crash if `userInfo` isn't castable to `Int`. Safer, but more verbose would look like:

```
func handleTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
    guard let index = timer.userInfo as? Int else { return }
    playEvent(index)
}
```

Comment: In the case of calling a `Selector` without parameters, and where userInfo is set to `nil` does the selector still take `(timer: NSTimer)` as its argument?

Comment: If you remove the colon at the end, no argument is passed. The state of `userInfo` is irrelevant.